# Flutter build ipa -allowProvisioningUpdates

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build, provisioning-profile

I'm working on a custom CI system using shell.

I have a script, that sets up a flutter project (according to a specified configuration). Basically it looks like that:

1. Read config
2. Read secrets
3. Create a new Flutter Project
4. flutter clean
5. Swap some files (like AndroidManifest.xml, Info.plist) in order to configure the app for release
6. flutter pub get
7. flutterfire configure
8. Swap app assets and generate app icons
9. A ruby script that enables push notifications capability
10. Build aab and ipa
11. Upload to GP and AS

Everything works fine, except the build ipa part. I get the error:

```
Error (Xcode): No profiles for 'x.y.z.a' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'x.y.z.a'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
/Users/me/Repos/mynewproject/mynewapp/ios/Runner.xcodeproj
```

The provisioning profile already exists in App Store Connect. I just need to make sure it's available for the build.

I suppose something is wrong with Xcodes automatic signing, I would need to find a way to programmatically configure the Xcode project so that it allows Provisioning Updates. Maybe is there a way to set something, so that the `-allowProvisioningUpdates` flag will be passed to xcodebuild, when running `flutter build ipa`?

Comment: did you mange to solve it?